# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError when creating object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a new object with `group.group_member.build` however this throws an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `group_member' for #<Group:0x007fe50d5468f8>
```

group.rb

```
belongs_to :owner
has_many :group_members
```

group_member.rb

```
belongs_to :group
```

I used `owner.build_group` which successfully created the group, I'm under the impression that `group.group_member.build` should do the same for the `group_member` object.

I have also tried `group.group_members.build` which returns a slightly different error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: group_id
```

All help is appreciated, I can't seem to figure out the issue here. Thanks.

Comment: `group.group_members.build` is correct syntax. Does `group_member` have a column for `group_id`?

Comment: As per Rails convention,it should be `group.group_members.build` only and `unknown attribute: group_id`  is because you may not have `group_id` in `group_members` table.

Comment: I realized that I messed up my migration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the name of the association, which is plural `group.group_members`. Update your code to use:

```
group.group_members.build
```

Your group_members table will need to have a `group_id` column for this to work.